# how to learn data from html by views in django

Tags: django

i create a html login.html

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

/* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
.tabcontent button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Admin')">Admin</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Facilitateur')">Facilitateur</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Entrepreneur')">Entrepreneur</button>
</div>

<div id="Admin" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2> Vous ètes un Admin ?</h2>

    <div class="container" action >
      <input type="hidden"  name="user" value="1">
      <label for ="id_email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
      <input id="id_email" type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>

      <label for ="id_password" ><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
      <input id="id_password" type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit" >Login</button>
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
      <span class="psw">oublier <a href="#">mot de passe?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>

<div id="Facilitateur" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <h2> Vous ètes un Facilitateur ?</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <input type="hidden"  name="user" value="3">
    <label for="email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="password"><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>

    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
    <span class="psw">Oublier <a href="#">Mot de passe?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</div>

<div id="Entrepreneur" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <h2> Vous ètes un Entrepreneur?</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="hidden"  name="user" value="2">
    <label for="email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>
    <label for="psw"><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>

    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
    <span class="psw">Oublier <a href="#">Mot de passe?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</div>
```

and i create a class in  forms.py to create a login fields

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
```

and this is my function in views.py to authenticates

```
def login(request):

    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "login.html")
    if request.POST:

        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if CustomUser.user_type == '1':
                    return render(request, "administrateur.html")
                elif CustomUser.user_type == '2':
                    return render(request, "entrepreneur.html")
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form

    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

i have two type of user entrepreneur and administrator

when in i put the email and the password in html and submit it stay in the same page(login.html)
i think (maybe) it s a simple problems in html and i didn't know how to send and learn fromhtml to views

Answer (score 1):

I see problem in your `login` view in line

```
if CustomUser.user_type == '1':
    return render(request, "administrateur.html")
elif CustomUser.user_type == '2':
    return render(request, "entrepreneur.html")
```

Here instead of checking model's attribute you need to check instance attribute ie. `user_type` like following

```
if user.user_type == '1':
    return render(request, "administrateur.html")
elif user.user_type == '2':
    return render(request, "entrepreneur.html")
```